# JS Event Listener with a function that has one parameter

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

Not sure how to set proper title for this question, so I guess that's why I can't find anything related to it.

Suggestion for title would be nice if this isn't a duplicate already.

I wonder how do I actually add/remove event listener with a function where I must pass one parameter.

Simple example as it should be is below:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', anFunction, false);
window.removeEventListener('resize', anFunction, false);
```

But how do I set the same function that must contain parameter within ? Example below that is invalid of course, as I don't know how to do it.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', anFunction(parameter), false);
window.removeEventListener('resize', anFunction(parameter), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use one of these:

- A wrapping function:

  ```js
  function resizeListener() {
      anFunction(parameter);
  }
  ```
- [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

  ```js
  var resizeListener = anFunction.bind(void 0, parameter);
  ```
- An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (EcmaScript6):

  ```js
  var resizeListener = e => anFunction(parameter);
  ```

And then:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener, false);
window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener, false);
```

Comment: I guess I have to go with wrapping function, because I need cross browser compatibility. Let me try !

Comment: @dvLden I would also choose that one. But be aware `bind` can be [polyfied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) for old browsers.

Comment: Oh thanks for polyfill :) ! Well I tried first method, I will try polyfill too but I guess wrapper will just do fine!

Answer (score 1):

There is also the relatively new (IE9+) [function.prototype.bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

It works like this:

```
var myVar = "123";

var myHandler = function(myVar) {
    console.log("Resize handler with arg: ", myVar);
    // => Resize handler with arg: 123
};

window.addEventListener("resize", myHandler.bind(this, myVar));
```

It's meant to be used for controlling the context (value of `this`) of callbacks, but it's also works nicely for things like what you described.

Comment: Is there any polyfill for cross browser support (IE 6 and above) ?

Comment: If you don't store any reference to the function returned by `myHandler.bind(this, myVar)`, you won't be able to remove the event listener.